# How to use a reference for GetPivotData's Data_Field argument?

Tags: excel-2007

I'm trying to use [`GetPivotData`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/getpivotdata-HP005209107.aspx) to query "Foo Bar" values from a pivot table. Just by typing `=` in a cell and clicking on the pivot table does most of the legwork, as Excel writes most of the formula. For example I get:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Foo Bar", 'Pivot Table'!D1, "Day", DAY(2010,10,10))       → 42
```

I need to have the first and last argument referenced to other cells and some extra dollars. I tried:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA($A$1, 'Pivot Table'!$D$1, "Day", $C3)                       → #REF!
```

...where `A1` contains `Foo bar` and `C3` contains `=DAY(2010,10,10)`.

This obviously gives a nice `#REF!`. Hardcoding the field name in the formula instead gives the correct value instead:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Foo Bar", 'Pivot Table'!$D$1, "Day", $C3)                 → 42
```

Is this an *undocumented* shortcoming of the function (all examples use an hardcoded field name, but nowhere is mentioned I can't use references for the first argument) or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> To fix this problem, you can concatenate an empty string ( "" ) at the end of the cell reference:
>
> ```
> =GETPIVOTDATA(B10 & "" ,$B$3,"Region",A11)`
> ```

from http://www.contextures.com/xlpivot06.html